# Item selection disappear after submit

Tags: javascript, php

I would like to ask some help for the following problem: I have a form with a combobox and a table. After page load the combo filled up with items using php and choosing an item from combo php creates a table with many other items. i have a click function for the table which selects the row i want to work with and seperately shows infos.
Everything works perfect. The problem is when i submit an update form (this is another form) then the page is refreshing and my selection is gone.
is there any way to get back my last selected item with the updated values?

I tried to keep the combo and table rowindex in variables and load back but after refreshing those datas are gone as well.

Comment: And your code please?!

Comment: You really need to supply your code...

Comment: My guess is you're using a form method of post with no ajax. Posting will push you to the target page causing a refresh, all your variables are gone. I would recommend using ajax to post data. This also cuts out on that annoying alert box if you refresh the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use cookies to store the combobox selected value and table rowindex instead of storing them in variables. If you are using jquery, then you can set cookies like this:

```
$.cookies.set('combo', '<selected_value>', {path : '/'}); // on click event of combobox
$.cookies.set('rowIndex','<table_rowindex>', {path : '/'}); // on click event of table
```

And after you page gets reloaded, you may get those like this:

```
var selected_value = $.cookies.get('combo', {path : '/'});
var table_rowindex = $.cookies.get('rowIndex', {path : '/'});
```

Then use those values to get back to your previous selection and show appropriate stuff.
Similar thing can be done using javascript only. Here is the link in case if you don't know the snytax :-
    http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp